# Not able to make PopOver menu in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display a popover menu on button click. It is giving me exception when i tried this code, i am not able to figure it out.
here is the code of popViewController which is subclass of UITableViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol popdelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) getdata;
@end
@interface popViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<popdelegate> delegate;
@end
```

This is the implementation of popViewController.m

```
#import "popViewController.h"
@interface popViewController ()

@end

@implementation popViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    _array = [NSMutableArray alloc];
    [_array addObject:@"New"];
    [_array addObject:@"Open"];
    [_array addObject:@"Shape"];
    NSInteger rowsCount = [_array count];
    NSInteger singleRowHeight = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView
                                           heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    NSInteger totalRowsHeight = rowsCount * singleRowHeight;

    CGFloat largestLabelWidth = 0;
    for (NSString *colorName in _array) {

        CGSize labelSize = [colorName sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
        if (labelSize.width > largestLabelWidth) {
            largestLabelWidth = labelSize.width;
        }
    }
    CGFloat popoverWidth = largestLabelWidth + 100;

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popoverWidth, totalRowsHeight);
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [_array count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
@end
```

Next is the code of my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "popViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<popdelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) popViewController *popmenu;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *controller;
-(IBAction)pop:(id)sender;
@end
```

And finally the ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}
-(IBAction)pop:(id)sender
{
if (_popmenu == nil) {
    _popmenu = [[popViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _popmenu.delegate = self;
}

if (_controller == nil) {
    _controller = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_popmenu];
    [_controller presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
                                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
} else {
    [_controller dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    _controller = nil;
}
}
- (void) getdata{    
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

When i run this and click on button which is supposed to show the menu, at that time i am getting an exception which i am not able to resolve. Please help me i am new to ios programming.

Comment: you are developing for iphone or ipad or universal?

Comment: i am developing for iPad and using iOS 7

Comment: can you post the exception?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object'

Comment: @Sumit Kumar The problem with your code is in the first line of your init method: ` _array = [NSMutableArray alloc];` you always want to call init immediately after every alloc like so: `_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

```
YourPopOverController * objPop = [[YourPopOverController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourPopOverController" bundle:nil];

UIPopoverController   *popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objPop];

 popOverController.delegate = self;

[popOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(266, 480)];

[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:yourBtn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

But Popover Its Only For Ipad....

Hop This Helps You...

Comment: You are initialising it with a xib file but i am using TableViewController. I want to know what is the problem with my code.